# Traveling salesman code not working (Java)

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

Traveling salesman code in java below (gives wrong result)

http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-solve-travelling-salesman-problem-unweighted-graph/

```
package com.hinguapps.graph;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TSP {
    private int numberOfNodes;
    private Stack < Integer > stack;

    public TSP() {
        stack = new Stack < Integer > ();
    }

    public void tsp(int adjacencyMatrix[][]) {
        numberOfNodes = adjacencyMatrix[1].length - 1;
        int[] visited = new int[numberOfNodes + 1];
        visited[1] = 1;
        stack.push(1);
        int element, dst = 0, i;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        boolean minFlag = false;
        System.out.print(1 + "\t");
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            element = stack.peek();
            i = 1;
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            while (i <= numberOfNodes) {
                if (adjacencyMatrix[element][i] > 1 && visited[i] == 0) {
                    if (min > adjacencyMatrix[element][i]) {
                        min = adjacencyMatrix[element][i];
                        dst = i;
                        minFlag = true;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (minFlag) {
                visited[dst] = 1;
                stack.push(dst);
                System.out.print(dst + "\t");
                minFlag = false;
                continue;
            }
            stack.pop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...arg) {
        int number_of_nodes;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of nodes in the graph");
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            number_of_nodes = scanner.nextInt();
            int adjacency_matrix[][] = new int[number_of_nodes + 1][number_of_nodes + 1];
            System.out.println("Enter the adjacency matrix");
            for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_nodes; j++) {
                    adjacency_matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_nodes; j++) {
                    if (adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1 &&
                        adjacency_matrix[j][i] == 0) {
                        adjacency_matrix[j][i] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The cities are visited as follows: ");
            TSP tspNearestNeighbour = new TSP();
            tspNearestNeighbour.tsp(adjacency_matrix);
        } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatch) {
            System.out.println("Wrong Input format");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Matrix should be :

```
0 10 5 40
2  0 5  1
6 13 0 12
1  8 9  0
```

Expected result: 1 3 2 4 1
Code result :  1 3 4 2 1

Answer (score 3):

This implementation is wrong. This is a hard problem, because you need to either touch every path, or at the very least CONSIDER every path. This implementation basically boils down to "Each step, move to the closest node that I haven't visited". Since the stack is not keeping memory of where you have been, it does not backtrack to consider that a better path may have existed down one of the longer roads.

To fix this, the algorithm needs to keep the path in memory somehow, and not start printing the solution until the best solution has actually been found. (Can use recursion, a stack that holds the whole path, or some other method.)